# SEM is not working in R-lavaan: missing observed variables in dataset

Tags: r, syntax-error, r-lavaan

I am running SEM package in R for path analysis.
Code and console are as follows. Please give me advice!

```
    head(data3)
    
    SR_model <- 'f1 ~ x1+x2+x3
                 f1 =~ f2+f3+f4
                 f2 =~ x4+x5+x6+x7
                 f3 =~ x8+x9
                 f4 =~ x10+x11
                 f5 ~ x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11'

    fit1 <- sem(SR_model, data3, std.lv=FALSE, estimator="DWLS")

> head(data3)
        x1        x2    x3  x4 x5 x6       x7  x8 x9 x10 x11
1 18.70668 0.8689024  65.0 127 77 53 1.649351 5.0 85 128  83
2 22.01236 1.0457516  71.0  89 68 43 1.308824 5.5 93 129  86
3 20.43588 0.9526270  68.4 201 80 39 2.512500 5.9 87 125  80
4 34.66844 1.5686275 116.5 138 50 80 2.760000 5.2 95 155 103
5 19.70858 0.9391534  80.0 146 82 63 1.780488 5.4 92 144  83
6 18.70634 0.9074410  65.0 127 86 45 1.476744 5.2 75 131  85
> 
> SR_model <- 'f1 ~ x1+x2+x3
>              f1 =~ f2+f3+f4
>              f2 =~ x4+x5+x6+x7
>              f3 =~ x8+x9
>              f4 =~ x10+x11
>              f5 ~ x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11'
> 
> fit1 <- sem(SR_model, data3, std.lv=FALSE, estimator="DWLS")
Error in lavaan::lavaan(model = SR_model, data = data3, std.lv = FALSE,  : 
  lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: f5
```

When I delete 'f5 ~ x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11', it works. But my path model needs this part.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, and verifies what your `head(data3)` shows: there is no variable `f5` in your data.  Is it supposed to be a latent variable, that you haven't defined (using the `=~` operator) in your syntax?

Comment: Thank you, Terrence. f5 is suppese to be a latent variable, but I want to draw that x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11 point(→) to f5. Can I do that? I suppose thtat it may not be allowed in SEM. Should a latent variable point to any varibales?

Comment: So `f5` is a formative construct?  You cannot identify that model unless it predicts something else.

Comment: I see. I will adjust this model  according to your advice.Thank you, Terrence!